# Can someone explain why this code print "Wild" in javascipt?

Tags: javascript

Hi I have a question about this code, why does it prints "Wild" instead of "Tabby"

```js
var cat = { name: "Athena" };

function swap(feline) {
    feline.name = "Wild";
    feline = { name: "Tabby" };
}
swap(cat);
console.log(cat.name);
```

Comment: From the marked duplicate: *Specifically, when you pass an object (or array) you are (invisibly) passing a reference to that object, **and it is possible to modify the contents of that object, but if you attempt to overwrite the reference it will not affect the copy of the reference held by the caller***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`feline` as an identifier is a local variable for your function. At the beginning it refers to `cat` from outside, and thus changing a part of the object is visible outside.

However when you set `feline` to a brand new object, that happens locally.

```js
var cat = { name: "Athena" };

function swap(feline) {
    console.log("feline, cat:",feline.name,cat.name,"feline===cat:",feline===cat);
    feline.name = "Wild";
    console.log("feline, cat:",feline.name,cat.name,"feline===cat:",feline===cat);
    feline = { name: "Tabby" };
    console.log("feline, cat:",feline.name,cat.name,"feline===cat:",feline===cat);
}
swap(cat);
console.log("cat:",cat.name);
```